# Can you click on a URL and do a large cross-domain POST request?

Tags: post, http-post

Consider the following code

```
<a
  href={someURL}
  onClick={() => {
    onEnterSurvey(args);
  }}
>
```

Assume that functions such as `event.preventDefault()` will not be called by the programmer (she/he didn't program it in the code).

Is it possible then to do a POST request?

Before the POST request happens and OPTIONS request will be sent.

Comment: "Functions such as event.preventDefault() will not be called" — They generally will. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Changed to: Assume that functions such as `event.preventDefault()` will not be called by the programmer (she/he didn't program it in the code).

Comment: Then the link would be followed by the request was made.

Answer (score -1):

In Firefox this didn't seem to work. In Google Chrome it did. However, when I changed the code to:

```
<a
  href='#'
  onClick={() => {
    onEnterSurvey(args);
  }}
>
```

it worked in both browsers.